# COMException was unhandled in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to pass `textbox1.text` value to crystal report.
Form1 has a `button1` and a `texbox1`, when I click `button1`, form2 will load with crystal report on it and display data that I put on `textbox1`.I Already created Parameters Field `Mytextbox` and put into crystalreport. When i run my program is says

> COMExceptions was unhandled

in this line

```
 Report.SetParameterValue("MyTextBox", Form1.TextBox1.Text)
```

[image]

Vb.net code

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Report As New ReportDocument
        Report.Load("C:\users\agent_edx44\Documents\Visual studio 2012\projects\sample\sample\sample.rpt")
        Report.SetParameterValue("MyTextBox", Form1.TextBox1.Text)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hmm, no, it says "Invalid index".  An obvious approach is to try "asdf" instead of "MyTextBox" and verify that it generates the same exception.  Then go looking at the report to see why "MyTextBox" is not correct.  Pay attention to casing.